# Is there a way to do null safe GORM dynamic finders?

Tags: grails, null, grails-orm

Is there a way ensure null safety in a GORM dynamic finder?

If I wanted to do something like `Book.findByName(author.bookname)`, I could guard against null authors by changing it to `Book.findByName(author?.bookname)` but how do I avoid an exception on nulls?

```
Book.findByName() is applicable for argument types: () values: []
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`auther?.bookname ? Book.findByName(author.bookname) : null //or do nothing`

Based on the fact from the example that `bookname` is `NOT NULL`.

or you can use `find`

`Book.find {name == author?.bookname} //Returns null if no records found`

Comment: I ended up going with the first approach a little while ago, but the second approach sounds like maybe a less verbose option.

Comment: Wouldn't the second approach match in the database where `name == null`?

Comment: Will you have a `Book` without a `name`? My answer has the fact assumption already. :)